# npm version (major, minor, patch) problem

Tags: node.js, npm

We have a Jenkins build running which has been working for at least a year but as of a week ago it stopped working. The build works for other nodejs projects and I have been able to manually walk through all the build steps without running into any issues.

The problem is that when we run npm version (major, minor, patch) it is, I believe, updating multiple lines in the package-lock.json file and only committing the changes for the first update/the top **version**.
As you can see below there are 2 json sections with name/version which seems fine as npm install created the file. However, when Jenkins runs npm version it is updating both the root **version** and the **version** inside the packages section.

```
    "version": "2.0.3-snapshot.0",
    "lockfileVersion": 2,
    "requires": true,
    "packages": {
        "": {
            "name": "@service",
            "version": "2.0.3-snapshot.0",
            "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
```

Which then creates.

```
    "version": "2.0.3",
    "lockfileVersion": 2,
    "requires": true,
    "packages": {
        "": {
            "name": "@service",
            "version": "2.0.3",
            "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
```

When I run npm version manually though it only updates the top version and commits the changes correctly. Any thoughts?

**Notes** I have checked that both the Node/npm version used by Jenkins and my testing were the same.

**edit: Adding all npm calls from pipeline** All the npm method calls just run "npm run ${goals} ${args}" I marked the line in the last section where it fails due to there being uncommitted changes and it therefore cannot do a merge.

```
npm(
    nodeHome: NODE_HOME,
    npmrcId: JENKINS_NPMRC,
    goals: "clean",
    args: ""
)

npm(
    nodeHome: NODE_HOME,
    npmrcId: JENKINS_NPMRC,
    goals: "build",
    args: ""
)

npm(
    nodeHome: NODE_HOME,
    npmrcId: JENKINS_NPMRC,
    goals: "test",
    args: ""
)

npm(
    nodeHome: NODE_HOME,
    npmrcId: JENKINS_NPMRC,
    goals: "lint:checkstyle",
    args: ""
)

nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: NODE_HOME, configId: JENKINS_NPMRC) {
    sh "git checkout develop"
    sh "git reset --hard origin/develop"

    sh "git checkout master"
    sh "git merge develop"

    sh "npm version ${params.RELEASE_VERSION.toLowerCase()}"
    RELEASED_VERSION = sh returnStdout: true, script: "node -p \"require('./package.json').version;\""
    RELEASED_VERSION = RELEASED_VERSION.trim()
    sh "npm publish --access restricted"
}

nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: NODE_HOME, configId: JENKINS_NPMRC) {
    sh "git checkout develop"
----FAILS HERE----
    sh "git merge master"

    // Increase development version
    sh "npm version --no-git-tag-version prepatch --preid=snapshot"
    sh "git commit -am \"Updating version for development\""

    // Push all changes to the server.
    sh "git push -u origin --all"
    sh "git push origin --tags"
}
```

Comment: might be best to show the pipeline steps here

Comment: @about14sheep Done and thank you. If you want the actual pipeline I can do that as well I just thought it would be a bit long.